# Post on a friend's wall on behalf of a user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am writing a Facebook application that needs to post on a friend's wall on behalf of a user, but out of the scope of a canvas application. I have the following:

- App ID
- App secret
- publish_stream permissions for the poster

This should theoretically be enough to do what I want to. What I am currently doing:

1. Use app ID and app secret to get an OAuth token representing my application (see "Authenticating as an Application" [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)).
2. Attempting to publish on my friend's wall using a POST on /friends_wall/feed (see [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#publishing)) and the OAuth token retrieved in step 1.

However, this ends up posting on the friend's wall as *the friend* rather than the user (the app also has publish_stream permissions for the friend). This isn't too unexpected, as nowhere in this process have I specified who the poster should be.

My question is: **Is it possible to obtain an OAuth token for an application representing a user? If not, is there any way to post on user's friend's wall outside the scope of a canvas application?**

Thanks,
Ashoat

Comment: Be aware that you will be no longer able to post to another user’s wall anymore via API from Feb 6. 2013, see https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/ The only way this will be possible after that point will be using the feed dialog, to have the user actively trigger it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I think I've figured out the answer here. I don't think that there's a way to do it in the new OAuth API, but there does seem to be a way with the older REST API. See the documentation [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish).

Simply replace step 2 in my question with the above documentation, still using the OAuth token from step 1, and you should be good :)

Comment: Actually I think I figured out the answer on Facebook chat Ashoat ;)

Comment: I think facebook wanted to get rid of this feature, it was probably abused way too much.

Answer (score 3):

Use below code for posting on friends wall:

```
NSMutableDictionary *paramspost = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"My test app", @"name",
                                   @"http://www.google.com", @"link",
                                   @"FBTestApp app for iPhone!", @"caption",
                                   @"This is a description of my app", @"description",
                                   @"Hello!\n\nThis is a test message\nfrom my test iPhone app!", @"message",
                                   nil];

// Publish.
// This is the most important method that you call. It does the actual job, the message posting.
[ facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"100001433267690/feed" andParams:paramspost andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

where "100001433267690" should be your friends userid in facebook