# How to share a link on another user's wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), I tried posting the following: `/[another_user_id]/links` and a link field
but I am getting this error:

> (#240) Requires a valid user is specified (either via the session or via the API parameter for specifying the user.

What am I missing here? Using `/[another_user_id]/feed` works but I want it to be a shared link.

Comment: I dont think that you can post to another user's wall on behalf of the user with the new OAuth API. This SO Post should be of some help to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536920/post-on-a-friends-wall-on-behalf-of-a-user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Following Code Posts In Users Friends wall.

```
try {
    $newStatus = $facebook->api("/$FRIENDSUSERID/feed", 'POST',
    array(
      'link' => "https://apps.facebook.com/XXXXXXXXX",
      'picture' => "https://XXXXXXXXX", //colour
      'name' => "XXXXXXXXX",
      'description' => "XXXXXXXXX",
      'access_token' => $access_token
     ));
     //echo '<pre>Post ID: ' . $newStatus['id'] . '</pre>';
} catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
        //echo '<textarea style="width: 300px; height: 200px;">' . $e->getMessage() . '</textarea>';
}
```

Comment: Ok, this works. But I want it to show a shared link, the one with the "<USER> shared a link via <APP>".